# Best way to handle audio file upload on nodejs server sent from mobile app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, google-cloud-speech

I'm building a (Spanish) speech to text app with expo/react-native. I'm sending audio files from the mobile app to my nodejs server (next), uploading those files to a local folder on the server with multer, using @google-cloud/speech to translate the audio files, then deleting the audio files from the server. It works fine when I run everything locally, but when I hit the production server I'm getting a 500 error at the upload step. I'm guessing it has to do with the upload function on the production server.

I'm wondering if there's a more optimized way to do this. Here is the code I'm using on the server:

```
const uploadStorage = multer.diskStorage({   
  destination: function(req, file, cb) { 
    cb(null, './temp-files');    
  }, 
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null , file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: uploadStorage,
}) 

const handler = nc();

handler.post(upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).json({transcript: await transcription(req.files[0].originalname)});
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(400).json({err});
  }
});

export default handler;

const transcription = (audioFile) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  const filename = `./temp-files/${audioFile}`;

  const file = fs.readFileSync(filename);
  const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

  // The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
  const audio = {
    content: audioBytes
  };
  
  const config = {
    encoding: 'LINEAR16',
    sampleRateHertz: 44100,
    languageCode: 'es-MX',
  };
  const request = {
    audio: audio,
    config: config,
  };

  // Detects speech in the audio file
  const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
  const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
    
  resolve(transcription);

  //Remove audio file when finished reading
  try {
    fs.unlinkSync(filename);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!